# Deno as Linux systemd service. How?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, deno

For reasons I don't understand, Deno is not a `systemd` service by default. It has an auto install script that drops the deno executable file in your `/home` folder. When you `deno run` a Typescript file using this executable, it loads up your script and them you can say goodbye to the console being used for anything else.

How do I add `deno` as a `systemd` service to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES! I figured it out!

Although, it would be really nice if you could help me figure out why `deno` only executes if you are logged in as a `root` user. I cannot get deno to run with sudo user.

Steps:

1. Install deno using the `.sh` script they provide at deno.land
2. Copy your `httpServer.ts` to your `/home` directory.
3. Tell `systemd` about the application by creating the service file we will be using.
4. `sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/deno.service`
5. Edit this recently created empty file using the template below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Deno 1.1.1 service
Documentation=http://deno.land
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=user1
WorkingDirectory=/home
ExecStart=/home/user1/.deno/bin/deno run --allow-net --allow-read httpServer.ts
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

6. Then enable and start it.

`sudo systemctl enable deno`

`sudo systemctl start deno`

7. Check status of deno service.

`sudo systemctl status deno`

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Deno won't run as a sudo user unless you have Deno installed for the superuser. Iirc Deno is a per-user install (~/.deno/)

Comment: Ok. So the correct way is to install Deno as root and then run it as root?

Comment: If you need it as root I presume; I run my stuff without root

Comment: Ok. From scratch, when I install deno from a sudo user account and attempt to run a script with read and net turned on, it still gives me permission errors. Why?

Comment: Argh! They don't exist anymore... So after installation, I don't need to set any file or folder permissions, correct? I guess the simplicity of deno blows my mind.

Comment: Lol yeah Deno is awesome; since you are running as super user you shouldnt really need to edit any folder permissions unless it isn’t working

Answer (score 0):

For a more up to date answer, have a look at https://deno.land/x/service

A combined cli tool or library which helps you install any script as a service with systemd, sysvinit, docker-init and launchd. It can also install a user mode service on systemd without the need for root access.

For a more versatile option, check out https://deno.land/x/pup , which is a fully featured process manager for Deno.